# R convert character vector values to Date values

Tags: r

i have vector with the following values.

```
> ga.nu$date
[1] "20150901" "20150902" "20150903" ...

> class(ga.nu$date) 
[1] character
```

i want to convert his values to date in the following structure

```
   >  ga.nu$date
   [1] "2015-09-01" "2015-09-02" "2015-09-03"

   >class(ga.nu$date)
   [1] "Date"
```

i've already trying

```
   > as.Date(ga.nu$date,"%Y-%m-%d)
   [1] NA NA NA
```

but i received null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format argument in the `as.Date()` function refers not to the target format but to the one you are trying to convert. So simple change your code to:

```
ga.nu$date = as.Date(ga.nu$date,"%Y%m%d)
```

Comment: thanks, how can i change the format for the vector in existing table